# Is low voltage resulting in overcharging me for electricity?

Tags: electrical-distribution

I notice I have low voltage in my home. I understand the standard is supposed to be 117 volts to the house and the nominal rating is 110 per pole or 220 total.

My house current consistently measures below this. My house is very close to the pole.

Is the meter only measuring actual current that I get, or does it *assume* a certain voltage and then measure a higher amount of current than was used if the voltage is different than the assumed voltage?

Answer (score 3):

A standard kWh meter measures both current *and* voltage directly, so no, don't worry about it -- it will compute correct usage no matter what the mains voltage does.